# Background PositioningCropping Issue

Tags: css, background

I am trying to replicate my Fiddle I have here on the website I am working on, but seems with the WidgetKit for Joomla the coding or CSS is effecting it. Fiddle is here: [http://jsfiddle.net/vZNj7/44/]

```
<div class="brand-wrap-bg">
<div class="image-cropper-brand" style="background-image: url('http://www.kanzenint.com/nkliq.com.au/nkliqjoom3/images/untitled-1_03.jpg');">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="brand-text">This is where the overview text is going to be</div>
</div>
```

This is my template so far: http://www.kanzenint.com/nkliq.com.au/nkliqjoom3/index.php/k2-users/k2-extra-fields/k2-extra-field-groups/k2-media-manager/k2-information/brand-story

You wont be able to see the DIV, but its under the top menu DIV at the moment (purposely as I want the background under the header)).

I also want to make it so that the browser window will crop the bottom if the window is resized or for people who have different window sizes.

I have been trying to work out why I cannot get it to work. Close to 5am and nesrly given up :(. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: I managed to get it working how I wanted (took me nearly 2 days now), but for some reason it doesnt want to display in IE.

Can anyone please help? Here is the link:

http://www.kanzenint.com/nkliq.com.au/nkliqjoom3/index.php/k2-users/k2-extra-fields/k2-extra-field-groups/k2-media-manager/k2-information/brand-story

Comment: Anyone? Seems getting no response :(

Answer (score 0):

I have worked it out after getting onto a Win8.1 machine and using the devtools on IE11 since the previous versions are such a piece of crap and next to not usable.

I was using the 'initial' for position but seems that IE does not like 'initial' and doesnt recognise it? So I used 'Static' instead and seems to get it to work.

The reason I needed to revert back to it as Widgetkit was using inline styles that couldnt be removed (well they probably could but I couldnt see it in the template) so the inline styles needed to be basically reverted back to a default value.

Hopefully this helps someone even though no one helped me :(